# Another invlid use of incomplete type

Tags: c++

I have been looking for a solution to this for a few days now. I will spare the details and just display the code:

```
#include "Mesh/GEdge.h"

//class GEdge;

class GEdgeSigned
{
 public:
  int _sign;
  GEdge *ge;
  GEdgeSigned(int i, GEdge *g) : _sign(i), ge(g) {}
  GVertex *getBeginVertex() const
  {
    return (_sign == 1) ? ge->getBeginVertex() : ge->getEndVertex();// Error here
  }
  GVertex *getEndVertex() const
  {
    return (_sign != 1) ? ge->getBeginVertex() : ge->getEndVertex(); // Error Here
  }
  void print() const;
  int getSign() const { return _sign; }
};
```

So basically, I have the invalid error at the locations marked. I clearly have the #include header at top and when you look into the header (the GEdge.h) there is no circular reference.

However, if you open a few more header files that are included in the GEdge.h file, you will end up with a circular reference.

So my question is this, if Edge.h is included 4 files deep, would this still be a circular reference causing the error?

If not, what are some other common issues that cause the invalid type error?

Comment: Circular is circular, no matter how many files this circle consists of.

Comment: So basically, I need to remove the circular reference

Comment: Yes. At least in the includes. Forward references and moving the function implementation to the cpp-file might help.

Comment: I see, thank you for your comments. This is actually code from an open source project so it looks like I have some editing to do, thank you!